# Read expiration date from jwt token

Tags: scala, jwt

I am using the jwt-core library ("com.pauldijou" %% "jwt-core" % "0.11.0"). I am given a JWT token and I want to read the expiration date from the token.

I looked at the examples they have on their github site and they have some angular and play framework examples.

https://github.com/pauldijou/jwt-scala/tree/master/examples

I want just plain scala code. No UI frameworks involved. Can you point me to a sample which helps me extract the expiration timestamp from the jwt token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWT is nothing more than a `base64` encoded and signed `string`.

I can't help you extracting the expiration date from your JWT, but I can help you by going through the steps of getting ***an*** expiration date from ***a*** JWT.

---

Here's a sample token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImV4cCI6MTIzNDIzNDIzNH0.ADaAdqIjKzQ4uPlavizyGyng2Vq1yQqYjcZ-EeqN8Do
```

You can check the decoded version by copying the example and decoding it at [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) with the code `secret`

The second part of the JWT is your payload, where the expiration date is most likely to live. You need to check the payload definition at the provider end and understand what are its attributes.

Now, for the Scala part:

First, having JWT formatted with JSON -- *JWT: JSON Web Token* -- you need to choose a JSON serializer/deserializer library. For this example I'm using `spray-json`.

```
import java.util.Base64
import spray.json._

case class Payload(sub: String, name: String, admin: Boolean, exp: Int) // exp is the expiration date

object ExpirationDateTest extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

implicit val payloadJsonFormat: RootJsonFormat[Payload] = jsonFormat4(Payload) // defines a contract to deserialize the JSON object

val jwtToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImV4cCI6MTIzNDIzNDIzNH0.ADaAdqIjKzQ4uPlavizyGyng2Vq1yQqYjcZ-EeqN8Do"

val jwtTokenPayload = jwtToken.split('.')(1)

val expirationDate = new String(Base64.getDecoder.decode(jwtTokenPayload)).parseJson.convertTo[Payload].exp

def getExpirationDate: Int = {
   expirationDate
}
}
println(ExpirationDateTest.getExpirationDate)
```

Results:

> 1234234234

Spray library used is : `"io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.2"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Using the scala-jwt library it was also quite easy.

```
import pdi.jwt._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._

val expTimeOpt = Jwt.decode(token, JwtOptions(signature = false, expiration = true, notBefore = false, leeway = 0)) match {
   case Success(s) => decode[JwtExpiration](s).fold[Option[JwtExpiration]](_ => Option.empty[JwtToken], Some(_))
   case Failure(f) => Option.empty[JwtExpiration]
}

case class JwtExpiration(exp: Long)
```

Comment: I went through `pdi.jwt` to find `JwtExpiration` but failed to do so. Only JwtExpirationException is available.